# How to set properly react-router-dom links with React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, endpoint

I've been struggling with my first solo proyect due to my lack of experience, here is the trouble I have:

I need to set a Link component (of react-router-dom) which takes me to another new page when I clicked the button. Thought that selection I need to pass to the link (and the context) the id so I can fetch the data from the API, but I cannot get an idea of how to make it works. This is the button link component:

**Model.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import FileModel from "../FileModel/FileModel";
import { ModelsContext } from "../../context/ModelsContext";

const Model = ({modelo}) => {

    const { id, name, year, price, photo } = modelo;

    const { guardarModelo } = useContext(ModelsContext);

    const [display, setDisplay] = useState("btn-notdisplayed");
    const showButton = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setDisplay("btn-displayed");
    };
  
    const hideButton = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setDisplay("btn-notdisplayed");
    };

 

    return (   
            <div 
                className="card"
                onMouseEnter={e => showButton(e)}
                onMouseLeave={e => hideButton(e)}
            >
                <div className="card-body">
                    <p className="card-name">{name}</p>
                    <p className="card-yearprice">{year} | $ {price}</p>
                </div>
                <img src={`https://challenge.agenciaego.tech${photo}`} className="card-image" alt={`Imagen de ${name}`} />
                <Router>
                    <button 
                        type="button" 
                        className={display}
                        onClick={() => {
                            guardarModelo(modelo);
                        }}
                    ><Link to={`/models/${modelo.id}`}>Ver Modelo</Link>
                    </button>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path={`/models/${modelo.id}`} component={FileModel} />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>         
            </div>   
     );
}
 
export default Model;
```

Then I obtained the data from a context:

**ModelsContext.jsx**

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const ModelsContext = createContext();

const ModelsProvider = (props) => {

        //State de modelos
        const [ modelo, guardarModelo ] = useState({});
        const [ modelos, guardarModelos ] = useState([]);
        const [ allModelos, guardarAllModelo ] = useState([]);
 

         //Cargar un modelo
         useEffect(() => {
             const consultarAPI = async () => {
                

                 const api = await fetch("https://challenge.agenciaego.tech/models");
                 const modelos = await api.json();

                 const api2 = await fetch(`https://challenge.agenciaego.tech/models/${id}`);
                 const modelo = await api2.json();
                 
                 guardarAllModelo(modelos);
                 guardarModelos(modelos);
                 guardarModelo(modelo);

             }
             consultarAPI()
         }, []);

    return (
        <ModelsContext.Provider
            value={{
                allModelos,
                modelo,
                modelos,
                guardarModelo,
                guardarModelos
            }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </ModelsContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default ModelsProvider;
```

Finally, I got the App.js from which I route the principal component, the idea Is to get with the Link to the new component called "FileModel.jsx" as a child component an so maintains the Navbar component.

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Nav/Navbar";
import Models from "./components/Models/Models";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Logo from "./assets/img/logo.png";
import ModelsProvider from "./context/ModelsContext";
import ModelFooter from "./components/Models/ModelFooter";

function App() {

  return (
    <ModelsProvider> 
        <Router>
            <nav className="navbar">
                <img src={Logo} className="logo" alt="Ego Logo" />
                <div className="menu-container">
                    <Link to={'/models'} className="menu-items">Modelos</Link>
                    <a className="menu-items">Ficha de modelo</a>
                </div>
                <div className="bottom-line"></div>
            </nav>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/models' component={Models} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
        <Navbar />
        <ModelFooter /> 
    </ModelsProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the fileModel.jsx so far:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import Navbar from "../Nav/Navbar";
import { ModelsContext } from "../../context/ModelsContext";

const FileModel = () => {

    const { modelo } = useContext(ModelsContext);

    console.log(modelo.id);

    return ( 
        <Navbar />
     );
}
 
export default FileModel;
```

I hope to have explained my issue clear, and thanks so much to all you caring people!

Cheers!

Ps: Maybe you can find some things to refactor (I will need to check my code later), If you find something like that any help will be appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Due to Linda recommendation I merged the two contexts into one, and changed some lines of the code I wrote before, I cannot set the state to pass the solo model to the fileModel component and the Link still not working, I was thinking in a functions that can do it, I made another state, a single modelo, but when I click the button I got an error and undefined, because Idk how to set in the state the Id and so pass it to the API call, the terminal says that id in const api2 = await fetch(`https://challenge.agenciaego.tech/models/${id}`); is not defined.

Comment: I really don't know what you're asking.  Can you share a link to a CodeSandbox and explain what part is not working?  You don't want that second `Router` declaration inside of `Model`.  Beyond that, I'm not really sure what the navigation is like.  It seems like you are trying to use the same component for both a thumbnail of a model and a page for a single model.  You don't want that.  You can share reusable pieces, but you want different components wrapping them.

Comment: So, this is the rought idea of what I need to do, I share two photos in this link. When you click the black button "Ver modelos", it should Link to a new component where you should get the details of the car in the new component which has to be display in the "Ficha del modelo" nav tag.

https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPr3KpCzqpcoXyXuVnofD_LFMRAsO5uJgomx4zHbDXh9UhtLfW22apefo7TClhn4Q?key=LXNUbktFU29SNXpQMm1zWDg3VVFWOTVOMDN4aXdn

Comment: I tried to access the API data with adding the id information of the button via context, but I'm very lost in that implementation of routing the endpoints.

Comment: I updated some of the code with your reccomendations, Linda (mostly the merge of the two contexts), try a bit, but still not working the redirection, idk where to put the Router in other place that could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FINALLY SOLVED MY PROBLEM!!! I had to rellocate some elements between my component to make the api context take the id and pass it to the FileModel component, and change the Link router to the App.js, this is how I get to the solution:

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Nav/Navbar";
import Models from "./components/Models/Models";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Logo from "./assets/img/logo.png";
import ModelsProvider from "./context/ModelsContext";
import ModelFooter from "./components/Models/ModelFooter";
import FileModel from "./components/FileModel/FileModel";


function App() {

  return (
    <ModelsProvider> 
        <Router>
            <nav className="navbar">
                <img src={Logo} className="logo" alt="Ego Logo" />
                <div className="menu-container">
                    <Link to={'/models'} className="menu-items">Modelos</Link>
                    <Link to={`/models/1`} className="menu-items">Ficha del Modelo</Link>
                </div>
                <div className="bottom-line"></div>             
            </nav>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/models' component={Models} />
              <Route exact path='/models' component={Models} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
        <Navbar />
        <FileModel />
        <ModelFooter />
    </ModelsProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Modelscontext.jsx**

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const ModelsContext = createContext();

const ModelsProvider = (props) => {

        //State de modelos
        const [ modelo, guardarModelo ] = useState([]);
        const [ modelos, guardarModelos ] = useState([]);
        const [ allModelos, guardarAllModelo ] = useState([]);

        
        const { id } = modelo;

         //Cargar un modelo
         useEffect(() => {
             const consultarAPI = async () => {
                

                 const api = await fetch("https://challenge.agenciaego.tech/models");
                 const modelos = await api.json();

                 const api2 = await fetch(`https://challenge.agenciaego.tech/models/${id}`);
                 const modelo = await api2.json();
                 
                 guardarAllModelo(modelos);
                 guardarModelos(modelos);
                 guardarModelo(modelo);

             }
             consultarAPI()
         }, [modelo.id]);

    return (
        <ModelsContext.Provider
            value={{
                allModelos,
                modelo,
                modelos,
                guardarModelo,
                guardarModelos
            }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </ModelsContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default ModelsProvider;
```

**Model.js**

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ModelsContext } from "../../context/ModelsContext";


const Model = ({modelo}) => {

    const { name, year, price, photo } = modelo;

    const { guardarModelo } = useContext(ModelsContext);

    const [display, setDisplay] = useState("btn-notdisplayed");
    const showButton = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setDisplay("btn-displayed");
    };
  
    const hideButton = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setDisplay("btn-notdisplayed");
    };

    return (   
            <div 
                className="card"
                onMouseEnter={e => showButton(e)}
                onMouseLeave={e => hideButton(e)}
            >
                <div className="card-body">
                    <p className="card-name">{name}</p>
                    <p className="card-yearprice">{year} | $ {price}</p>
                </div>
                <img src={`https://challenge.agenciaego.tech${photo}`} className="card-image" alt={`Imagen de ${name}`} />
                    <Link to={`/models/${modelo.id}`}><button 
                        type="button" 
                        className={display}
                        onClick={() => {
                            guardarModelo(modelo);
                        }}
                    >Ver Modelo
                    </button></Link>
            </div>   
     );
}
 
export default Model;
```

**FileModel.js** (so far...)

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import Navbar from "../Nav/Navbar";
import { ModelsContext } from "../../context/ModelsContext";

const FileModel = () => {

    const { modelo } = useContext(ModelsContext);

    const { photo, name } = modelo;

    return (
        <> 
        <Navbar />
        <section>
            <img src={`https://challenge.agenciaego.tech${photo}`} alt={`Imagen de ${name}`}/>
        </section>
        </>
     );
}
 
export default FileModel;
```

Thanks to Linda for giving me the input to refactoring the context! cheers!